# Am I allowed to use variables in my facts / rules?

Tags: prolog

I'm working through the first problem in a famous collection of [99 Prolog problems](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Emeidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/). Here is the question:

> Find the last element of a list. Example: ?- my_last(X,[a,b,c,d]). X = d

and here is my file of facts and rules:

```
my_last(_, []).
my_last(_, [H | T]) :- my_last(H, T).
```

and my query:

```
my_last(X, [a,b,c,d]).
```

My output is `true`, but I want my output to be the value of the variable `X` when the computer gets to the point that evaluates to true. I used `trace`, and I think the program works much as I expected it to. Basically, it runs through `my_last(a, [b, c, d])` and so on until `my_last(d, [])`, then evaluates to true and starts backing out of the recursion. But it still only evaluates to true! Why is this happening? Is it because I have variables in my facts/rules?

Comment: I don't want to answer because gusbro's answer is good; just commenting what's going wrong: The line: `my_last(_, []).` says "anything is valid as the last element of an empty list". e.g. the last element of `[]` could be `potato`, which is not right. So your code recurses down the list, past the actual last element, until it gets to the empty list. `my_last(X, [])` has X as an unbound variable, and that rule says it's fine for an unbound variable to be the last thing in an empty list; not right. Recursion doesn't *have* to consume an entire list, or have the empty list as its base/end case.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I guess my original formulation goes wrong when someone queries `my_last(potato, []).` because this will ALWAYS evaluate to true. But assume we only enter non-empty lists as the second argument to `my_last`. What is the issue in that case?

Comment: then [H|T] will pick off the first element into H, and you call my_last on T, so that keeps reducing the list. All lists have an implied empty list at the end, so `[a,b,c,d]` is also written `[a,b,c,d|[]]`, so it always gets to that case eventually. And you start by passing in X as an unbound variable, the chain unravels down through (a, [b,c,d]) then (b, [c,d]) then (c,[d]), then (d, []), all those are fine, so X as an unbound variable is fine, it's all true. As gusbro says, nowhere does X get given any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is giving you just true because at the end there are no bindings performed.

The head of your second clause has an anonymous variable as the first argument, there is no instantiation of `X` in `my_last(X, [a,b,c,d])`.

You may rewrite your procedure to unify it with the last element of the list in the first clause, then chain it back all the way through the recursive step (second clause):

```
my_last(H, [H]).
my_last(H, [_ | T]) :- my_last(H, T).
```

Sample run:

```
?- my_last(X, [a,b,c,d]).
X = d ;
false.
```

Note the choice point left in this program which eventually will fail upon backtracking for further solutions.

You may improve this program by letting first argument indexing kick in by rewriting the procedure like this:

```
my_last(X, [H|T]):-
  my_last(T, H, X).
  
my_last([], X, X).
my_last([H|T], _, X):-
  my_last(T, H, X).
```

which now gives us:

```
?- my_last(X, [a,b,c,d]).
X = d.
```